# Is there any way to change the value of Color name in android?

Tags: android

I want to change the whole app color at run time. When I start my app, I have to hit an api which returns me a RGB color value and I have to change whole app color accordingly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
ThemeColors.setNewThemeColor(MainActivity.this, red, green, blue);
```

Comment: No. This method does not have a parameter for theme name. Actually I want to override my colorPrimary. When I call an api it return me a color, then I want to set that color value on my colorPrimary

Comment: ThemeColors.setNewThemeColor(MainActivity.this, red, green, blue); call again and again

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can set the colors even without a declared theme. It's a static method.

Answer (score -1):

1. Set your colors value in res/values/colors.xml

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

then

2. Set your styles in res/values/styles.xml

Example:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

At run-time it will use these settings.

Comment: He wants to change them on the fly during runtime

Comment: Oooh, I see. Was wondering why I received the -1 :) Thanks, makes sense now.